# Get Week of the Year returning wrong week number

Tags: c#, datetime

I am using the code below to get the current week of the year:

```
DateTimeFormatInfo dfi = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;
Calendar cal = dfi.Calendar;
cal.GetWeekOfYear(DateTime.Now, dfi.CalendarWeekRule, dfi.FirstDayOfWeek);
```

Right now its `19-02-2016` and the week number is `7`, but the code above returns display `8`.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the code?

Comment: Now is week `8`. There is nothing wrong with the code... Why do you think that now is week `7`?

Comment: I had a similar problem, and I found this which helped me;  Sorry, can't remember the original source.       https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnste/2006/01/24/iso-8601-week-of-year-format-in-microsoft-net/

Comment: @Ian According to some week number rules yes, according to others no. The OP does not specify which week number rules to use (the OP's system default, but which is that?), so we cannot say whether the OP's result is supposed to be `7` or `8`.

Comment: @hvd I see. I typically only work locally - wasn't aware of this...